# Firebase InApp Messaging not working with Android OS 6.0.1

Tags: firebase-in-app-messaging

I am trying to integrate Firebase InApp messaging in my android application. After adding below dependency in gradle 
implementation *'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:18.0.2'*

**Its throwing below error :**
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
 io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:69)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
        at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:125)
        at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.(GrpcUtil.java:203)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:84)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:119)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:48)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:27)
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:73)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcChannelModule.providesGrpcChannel(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:41)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcChannelModule_ProvidesGrpcChannelFactory.providesGrpcChannel(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:36)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcChannelModule_ProvidesGrpcChannelFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:26)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcChannelModule_ProvidesGrpcChannelFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:9)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.components.DaggerUniversalComponent.gRPCChannel(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:280)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.components.DaggerAppComponent$com_google_firebase_inappmessaging_internal_injection_components_UniversalComponent_gRPCChannel.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:437)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.components.DaggerAppComponent$com_google_firebase_inappmessaging_internal_injection_components_UniversalComponent_gRPCChannel.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:424)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcClientModule_ProvidesInAppMessagingSdkServingStubFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:35)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcClientModule_ProvidesInAppMessagingSdkServingStubFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:11)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.GrpcClient_Factory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:23)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.GrpcClient_Factory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:8)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.ApiClient.getFiams(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@18.0.2:8)

This works fine with other Android OS , have verified with 7.0, 8.0 and 9.0.
Note : Have added **androidx** support.

these are my gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
    //noinspection GradleDependency,OutdatedLibrary
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.21'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.21'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Has anyone come across this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Guava to the dependencies, it seems to fix the issue:

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-android'
```